# Calculate difference of percentage changes of years in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a revenue dataset consisting of revenue of categories across different dates.

```
cat    revenue    date
A       100      10-01-2017
B       120      10-01-2017
A       100      11-01-2017
...     ...          ...   
B       320      10-12-2020
```

This contains 4 years of dataset.

I'm looking to create a measure which gives me:

`(Percentage change in revenue current year - Percentage change in revenue previous year).`

For eg: I need to find out `(Percentage change in revenue 2020 - Percentage change in revenue 2019).`

By percent change revenue, i meant - `(previous years revenue - current years revenue)/ previous years revenue`

For example, if i visualize it in a matrix visualization, I intend to get:

```
cat   Percentage change in revenue 2020  Percentage change in revenue 2019  Difference
 A                   11                                 15                      -4
 B                   31                                 28                       3
```

I have read blogs which says i need to use **SAMPLEPERIODLASTYEAR** DAX function to do this.
I tried with the same, but the *Difference* always comes 0.0.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you already have measure for "Percentage change in revenue 2020" & "Percentage change in revenue 2019"? If yes, please add codes for them in the question.

Comment: @mkRabbani No i need to create those measures as well

Comment: What is the logic for calculating Percent Change?

Comment: @mkRabbani By percent change, i meant the (pervious years revenue - current years revenue)/pervious years revenue

Comment: @mkRabbani for eg: for cat A, suppose on Jan2020 the revenue was 150, so need find out what was its revenue on Jan2019(at a month level, since it may happen on the exact same date of last year I might not have the record.) Therefore if i get to know on Jan 2019 the revenue was 200. So (200-150)/200. This calculation can then be aggregated at a year level

Answer (score 0):

**First**, create this below 3 measure for years-

```
year_this = YEAR(TODAY())
```

```
year_last = YEAR(TODAY()) - 1
```

```
year_last_previous = YEAR(TODAY()) - 2
```

**Now**, create this below 3 measures for calculating Revenue for above 3 years-

```
revenue_this_year = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[revenue]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[cat]),
        YEAR(your_table_name[date]) = [year_this]
    )
)
```

```
revenue_last_year = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[revenue]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[cat]),
        YEAR(your_table_name[date]) = [year_last]
    )
)
```

```
revenue_last_previous_year = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM(your_table_name[revenue]),
    FILTER(
        ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[cat]),
        YEAR(your_table_name[date]) = [year_last_previous]
    )
)
```

**Finally**, create these below 2 measure to calculate the Revenue changes. Change the Measure type to **%** from the Menu bar.

```
revenue_change_this_year = 
IF(
    [revenue_this_year] = 0 || [revenue_last_year]= 0,
    "-",
    ([revenue_this_year]-[revenue_last_year])/[revenue_last_year]
)
```

```
revenue_change_last_year = 
IF(
    [revenue_last_year] = 0 || [revenue_last_previous_year]=0,
    "-",
    ([revenue_last_year]-[revenue_last_previous_year])/[revenue_last_previous_year]
)
```